# Applescript how to change desktop mode (Fill Screen, Tile, Centre, etc)

Tags: macos, applescript, desktop, macos-mojave, wallpaper

Hi so I'm pretty new to applescript and trying to make an applescript program that has a list of 5 names, with corresponding images. So if someone clicks one of the buttons, desktop will change to that persons image.

Here is what I've got so far;

`display dialog "Which Person?" buttons {"1", "2"}
if the button returned of the result is "1" then
    tell application "System Events" to tell every desktop to set picture to "/Users/jamiecole/Desktop/TeacherTiles.app/Contents/Resources/Images/1.jpg"`

`else
    tell application "System Events" to tell every desktop to set picture to "/Users/jamiecole/Desktop/TeacherTiles.app/Contents/Resources/Images/2.jpg"
end if`

I need to make the mode to Tile, see this
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXqOc.png). How can I do this within an applescript? Thanks so much!

Comment: Without resorting to UI scripting, which I don't view as a reasonable solution, I don't see a scripting method that provides the option to tile the desktop background image.  It's possible to set the background image to stretch to match the dimensions of the desktop; to grow/shrink proportionately until it fills the desktop with a maximally-visible area of the image; to grow/shrink proportionately to maximise the size of the image whilst keeping it fully contained within the desktop; or to centre it, without adjusting size.